# Does the Qt framework support manipulating videos files?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Using the Qt framework is there a way to add watermarks to videos? If not what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to embedd something into a video you have to reencode the video. for this you have to extract frame by frame, add your watermark to each frame and reencode each frame.

i would use `ffmpeg` for this task.

qt and it's multimedia framework might help to decode a video, i am not aware of the encoding part. so, to answer your question: no.

might be helpful: http://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/ (which has some prebuilt win32 binaries in the repository [already](http://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/source/browse/#svn/trunk/ffmpeg_lib_win32))

Comment: can I use ffmpeg on both OS X and Windows?

Comment: yes: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html for windows-binaries, building them yourself might be a bit painful (allthough high educational value).